# Can't get \hangfootparindent to work with \footmisc

Tags: footnotes, indentation, paragraphs, footmisc, ragged2e

I use `\footmisc` to style my footnotes, with the `hang` option (in combination with `raged2e`). I'd like to set the second and subsequent paragraphs in multiparagraph notes with an indentation, but can't get `\hangfootparindent` to work. Both new lines within a paragraph and new paragraphs are indented based on the `\RaggedRightParindent` value. I'd like new grafs to be indented and new lines within a graf to *not* be indented; but indenting new grafs is more important.

Edit: as indicated in the solution from @touhami, this is related to the option `ragged`. Removing that option makes the indentation work correctly but then the footnotes are set justified, which I don't want.

It seems like I'm missing something easy and obvious, but I can't for the life of me figure it out!

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,article,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{1em}
\usepackage[ragged,hang,norule,splitrule,bottom]{footmisc}
\renewcommand\hangfootparindent{5em}
\renewcommand\hangfootparskip{0\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas
placerat justo ac orci iaculis, ut dictum velit blandit. Suspendisse
potenti.\footnote{Multiple paragraphs! Graf 1 Line 1\\In-paragraph line break. Graf 1 Line 2

Totally new graf. Graf 2 Line 1}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas
placerat justo ac orci iaculis, ut dictum velit blandit. Suspendisse
potenti.\

\end{document}
```

No matter what value I give `\renewcommand\hangfootparindent` (5em, .5em, etc.) it always looks the same:

[image: MWE notes]

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know you will be using `ragged2e`, and the `hang` and `ragged` options of `footmisc`, then you could do this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,article,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{1em}
\usepackage[ragged, hang, norule,splitrule,bottom]{footmisc}
\renewcommand\hangfootparskip{0\baselineskip}
\renewcommand\hangfootparindent{5em}

\makeatletter
\ifFN@para
\else
  \long\def\@makefntext#1{%
    \ifFN@hangfoot
      \bgroup
      \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{%
        \ifdim\footnotemargin>0pt
          \hb@xt@\footnotemargin{\@makefnmark\hss}%
        \else
          \@makefnmark
        \fi
      }%
      \leftmargin\wd\@tempboxa
      \rightmargin\z@
      \linewidth \columnwidth
      \advance \linewidth -\leftmargin
      \parshape \@ne \leftmargin \linewidth
      \footnotesize
      \@setpar{{\@@par}}%
      \leavevmode
      \llap{\box\@tempboxa}%
      \parskip\hangfootparskip\relax
      \parindent\hangfootparindent\relax
    \else
      \parindent1em
      \noindent
      \ifdim\footnotemargin>\z@
        \hb@xt@ \footnotemargin{\hss\@makefnmark}%
      \else
        \ifdim\footnotemargin=\z@
          \llap{\@makefnmark}%
        \else
          \llap{\hb@xt@ -\footnotemargin{\@makefnmark\hss}}%
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
%     \footnotelayout#1 % <-- orig; \bgroup to \egroup added
      \bgroup
      \setlength\RaggedRightParindent{5em}%
      \RaggedRight
     #1
     \egroup
    \ifFN@hangfoot
      \par\egroup
    \fi
  }
\fi
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\noindent
\lipsum*[1]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas
placerat justo ac orci iaculis, ut dictum velit blandit. Suspendisse
potenti.\footnote{Multiple paragraphs! Graf 1 Line 1\\In-paragraph line break. Graf 1 Line 2 \lipsum*[1]

Totally new graf. Graf 2 Line 1}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas
placerat justo ac orci iaculis, ut dictum velit blandit. Suspendisse
potenti.\

\end{document}
```

More work needs to be done if you want to patch `footmisc` so it does 'the right thing' regardless of whether you load `ragged2e` or not.

Comment: Thanks! Just curious—is there a reason why this is so complicated? Is it easier without the `hang` option? If this is too complicated to explain, no need to do so! Thanks again!

Comment: @hgv -- Hanging the footnotes is complicated, compounded by the fact that the package is designed to work no matter which different options are chosen. (I'm not sure if you have simply found an unintended option conflict. You might want to email the package author, though I believe he frequents this site on occasion.)  If you want to tidy it up, you could move the code between the `\makeat...` commands into a separate `.sty` that you load.  With a minor modification, you could also make it so you can set the `\RaggedRightParindent` in the `.tex` file.  I can edit the answer if you like.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[12pt,article,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{1em}
\usepackage[hang,norule,splitrule,bottom]{footmisc}
\renewcommand\hangfootparindent{1em}
\renewcommand\hangfootparskip{0\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas
placerat justo ac orci iaculis, ut dictum velit blandit. Suspendisse
potenti.\footnote{\indent Multiple paragraphs! Graf 1 Line 1\\In-paragraph line break. Graf 1 Line 2

Totally new graf. Graf 2 Line 1}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas
placerat justo ac orci iaculis, ut dictum velit blandit. Suspendisse
potenti.\

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this does make the indentation work, but it also removes the `ragged` option from `footmisc`, making the footnotes set justified, which I don't want. But it helps clarify the problem a bit, so thanks!